# Cancellationtoken exception not executing

Tags: c#, wpf, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I need to cancel following async method by clicking on button.

This is what i tried:

```
private CancellationTokenSource cts;

    private async Task<bool> ValidateFtpAsync()
    {

        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = cts.Token;
        try
        {
            return await Task.Run(
                    () =>
                    {

                        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                        Global_Variables.DoingStuff = true;

                        if (File.Exists("settings.xml"))
                        {
                            var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Information));
                            using (var read = new FileStream("settings.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                            {

                                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                                Information info = (Information)xs.Deserialize(read);

                                try
                                {
                                    var DecryptedInfo = FileCryptoDecryptor.ReadEncryptedConfiguration("hakuna.xml.aes", Global_Variables.AppPassword);
                                    string DecryptedFTPPass = EncryDecryptor.Decrypt(DecryptedInfo.FtpPassword, "blablabla");
                                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                                    return General_Functions.isValidConnection(info.HDSynologyIP, info.FtpUsername, DecryptedFTPPass);
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                                }
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Missing settings file.");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }, token);
        }
        catch(OperationCanceledException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Canceled test");
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cts.Cancel();
    }
```

I'm **not** getting any cancel exception message when i click on the button.

The function it self is returning if ftp connection is connected with following line:

```
return General_Functions.isValidConnection(info.HDSynologyIP, info.FtpUsername, DecryptedFTPPass);
```

And this function is not async and takes a most of the time executing could that cause a problem?

Looks like this:

```
 public static bool isValidConnection(string url, string user, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            FtpClient client = new FtpClient(url);
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password);
            client.SocketPollInterval = 60000;
            client.ConnectTimeout = 60000;
            client.ReadTimeout = 60000;
            client.DataConnectionConnectTimeout = 60000;
            client.DataConnectionReadTimeout = 60000;
            client.Connect();

            bool IsItConnected = client.IsConnected;

            if (IsItConnected == true)
            {
                client.Disconnect();
                client.Dispose();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                client.Disconnect();
                client.Dispose();
                return false;
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            LogWriter loger = new LogWriter(ex.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

//EDIT

Ftpclient is from FluentFTP library: https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on `MessageBox.Show` does the debugger stop there when you click the button?  You mightn't be seeing the message because its running in a child thread?

Comment: @MickyD Nope but when i click fast enough i get messagebox with "operation was canceled" thats why im suspecting return function

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your method checking whether the connection is valid doesn't respect the cancellation token at all. If it's blocked performing a network operation, simply nothing will happen until it finishes even if you cancel the token.
If your FTP client takes most of the whole processing time and there are no asynchronous overloads accepting a CancellationToken, then it's practically uncancellable and throws away all the advantages you expect to gain from the CancellationToken.

Second, if the cancellation happens in the innermost try block, the OperationCanceledExceptions gets suppresses by your `catch (Exception)` part. You should rethrow the exception if it's OperationCanceledException.

```
                           try
                            {
                                var DecryptedInfo = FileCryptoDecryptor.ReadEncryptedConfiguration("hakuna.xml.aes", Global_Variables.AppPassword);
                                string DecryptedFTPPass = EncryDecryptor.Decrypt(DecryptedInfo.FtpPassword, "blablabla");
                                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                                return General_Functions.isValidConnection(info.HDSynologyIP, info.FtpUsername, DecryptedFTPPass);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex) when (!(ex is OperatiomCanceledException))
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                            }
```